# Auto detection of links fails in UITextView if the URL is too large

Tags: ios, url, hyperlink, uilabel, uitextview

My current URL is of length 801 characters. What I discovered is auto detection of links doesn't work in UITextView if the URL length is above 350 characters. Also I tested my link in "Messages" app it doesn't work(messages would use a UILabel or UITextView for showing text content). Is there any way we can detect the URL above 350 characters length?

Answer (score 0):

If the data detector of UITextView could not able to detect the URL with length is above 350 characters as your investigation, I think you could be able to do that by your own with regular expression. After detecting the URL, you could use attributedString to set to the UITextView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0);

    NSString *testString = @"google dog meme  https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=dog+meme&espv=2&biw=1672&bih=890&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWr8rexqXSAhUO9GMKHYHXD7QQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=doge+meme&imgrc=SFF-4BKQucOc4M: hhahaa";
    NSDataDetector *detect = [[NSDataDetector alloc] initWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [detect matchesInString:testString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [testString length])];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:testString attributes:nil];
    NSTextCheckingResult *result = matches.firstObject;
    if (result) {
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:result.URL.absoluteString range:result.range];
    }
    self.textView.editable = NO;
    self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;
    self.textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.textView.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange {
    NSLog(@"#### %@", URL);
    return YES;
}
```

Another approach is that using URL shortener to shorten your URL first, then display them. I think this is valuable in term of UX because users they might not willing to click on a really long URL.

I hope this would help you.

Comment: Hmm, it worked from my side, what is the problem you got?

Comment: Can you try with any URL of above 350 characters?. Thanks for url shortener suggestion.

Comment: Tested with `URL length 1332` and it worked.  I could able to highlight the URL and it is clickable. Did you set `self.textView.editable = NO;` ?